# How do I use BETWEEN and AND in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

HI I am trying to use the following and not  sure how to get this fixed

```
SELECT * FROM search_users  
WHERE 
  match(first_name,last_name,country,city,location,nationality,short_bio) 
  against (?)   
AND 
  search_users.loc_lng BETWEEN '-0.24272918701172' AND '-0.24272918701172' 
AND 
  search_users.loc_lat BETWEEN '51.47026338272' AND '51.47026338272'
```

I am trying to write a `laravel` query that does exactly the same as

```
select * from search_users  
where 
  ......   
  and search_users.loc_lng BETWEEN '-0.24272918701172' AND '-0.24272918701172' 
  AND search_users.loc_lat BETWEEN '51.47026338272' AND '51.47026338272'
```

Comment: Not answering your question but worth mentioning: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: The problem is to create the query in laravel not how to use the geo locations... sorry if my question was not clear at the first time

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you just want to build the query / get pure data without any logic around it, you can simply use the Query Builder:

```
$results = DB::table('search_users')
           ->where('first_name', $firstname)
           ->where('last_name', $last_name)
           ->where('country', $country) //and so on
           ->whereBetween('loc_lng', array(-0.24272918701172, -0.24272918701172))
           ->whereBetween('loc_lat', array(51.47026338272, 51.47026338272))
           ->get();
```

And sure enough you can use the same syntax if you're working with a Model:

```
$users = User::where('key1', $value1)
             ->where('key2', $value2)
             ->whereBetween('loc_lng', array(-0.24272918701172, -0.24272918701172))
             ->whereBetween('loc_lat', array(51.47026338272, 51.47026338272))
             ->get();
```

A little additional explanation concerning your question about how to use `AND` in eloquent:

`AND` is used by default if you use 2 or more `where()`s. So

```
DB::table('search_users')->where('first_name', $firstname)
                         ->where('last_name', $last_name)
```

equals

```
SELECT * FROM search_users  WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?
```

For `OR` you can use `orWhere()`:

```
DB::table('search_users')->where('first_name', $firstname)
                         ->orWhere('last_name', $othername)
```

which equals

```
SELECT * FROM search_users  WHERE first_name = ? OR first_name = ?
```

And sometimes you may need something more complicated, for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM search_users  
WHERE first_name = ? 
  AND (last_name = ? OR last_name = ?)
  AND age > 27
```

In Eloquent, this would be:

```
DB::table('search_users')
      ->where('first_name', $firstname)
      ->where(function($query) {
          $query->where('last_name', $lastName1);
          $query->orWhere('last_name', $lastName2);
      })
      ->where('age', '>', 27)
```