# Laravel - select row between start date and end date using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to convert this query into laravel eloquent,

```
select * from schedule where (now() between start_date and end_date);
```

I tried using whereBetween, but I got some error.

```
$schedule = Schedule::whereBetween(Carbon::now(), ['start_date', 'end_date'])->get();
```

the error looks like this

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2017-06-01 06:17:30' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `schedule` where `2017-06-01 06:17:30` between start_date and end_date)

any idea?

Comment: The first parameter of `whereBetween` should be a column name, not a value

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$from = $request->from;
$to = $request->to;
$title="Sales From: ".$from." To: ".$to;
$sales = Sale::whereBetween('created_at', [$from.' 00:00:00',$to.' 23:59:59'])->get();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$schedule = Schedule::where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now())
    ->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->get();
```

Or

```
$schedule = Schedule::whereRaw('(now() between start_date and end_date)')->get();
```

Comment: Can you help me with my query, I've 2 columns start_at and end_at and need data between these 2 dates but also I've 2 date to check on, I will not check using now(),

I've 2 new date start_at and end_at

Answer (score 6):

The whereBetween is used only when you want to find a row where a single column is between 2 values, what you want to do is :

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$schedule = Schedule::where('start_date', '<=', $now)
    ->where('end_date', '>=', $now)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

whereBetween should used [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22177299/6521116), `->whereBetween('loc_lng', array(-0.24272918701172, -0.24272918701172))` whose first parameter is the column name, and the second is the region.

In you situation you can use  `->where('start_date', '<' Carbon::now())->where('end_date', '>' Carbon::now());`

Comment: Can you help me with my query, I've 2 columns start_at and end_at and need data between these 2 dates but also I've 2 date to check on, I will not check using now(),

I've 2 new date start_at and end_at

Comment: You can use the second way in my answer, and change the `Carbon::now()` to your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereBetween('date_field',[$from_date, $to_date])` to fetch the data between two dates but it should be in the array format.

```
$products = Sale::with('products')
    ->whereBetween('date',[$from_date, $to_date])
    ->get();
return response()->json($products);
```

You can also use `whereBetween(whereBetween('date_field',[$from_date, $to_date]))` with multiple where conditions like:

```
$products = Sale::with('products')
    ->whereBetween('date',[$from_date, $to_date])
    ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('employee_id', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
          ->orWhere('employee_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->get();
return response()->json($products);
```

I hope this will work for you :)